# Android image displaying differently despite same pixel density

Tags: android

I have two different png's BOTH are 48px x 48px. However, when I assign both to an imageView, one of the images displays larger than the other. The code i have is as follows:

```
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                iconID = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                break;
            case 1:
                iconID = R.drawable.gmail;
                break;
        }
```

The above image is displayed in the following imageview:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/statusIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

The launcher icon is about 1.5x bigger than the gmail in my listview even though they are the EXACT same pixel size. What is going on?

Comment: I think you inadvertently gave the answer in your title "pixel density" is at stake. Are the resources in the same dpi-folder? If so, do they have the same dpi?

Comment: Are they from the same `resources/drawable` folder, with no `dpi`-specific overloads for the other?

Comment: yes they are both in the same dpi folder

Comment: I still suspect that theory. `ic_launcher` smells like it's generated by a wizard, with a overload for each dpi. If you placed the `gmail` drawable in a higher dpi folder than you device is, it would get scaled down to a smaller size while the `ic_launcher` does not need downscaling.

Comment: there is only one ic_launcher file and one gmail file in the res/drawable folder. the other drawable folders are empty. I am testing with a nexus4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes android will try to scale the pictures on the fly. Try putting them in a raw res folder and if it was the system trying to scale things that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try using for both the images

```
android:background="@color/Transparent"                //or whatever your background color is  


        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/musicxml"//           you can use left right etc
```